# Contact Form Plugin how to send to different recipients based on country selected?

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm trying to build a plugin that fires on the Contact Form Plugins `contactForm.beforeSend`what the plugin needs to do is add a recipient email if certain countries are selected. So far I have created the below which checks for the countries and checks against an array to see if they are in it. This works, so far so good. What I need to do now is somehow add to the contact form plugins `$toEmails` variable if a country is in the array but I'm not sure how to do this from within the event listener. Is this even possible?

```
public function init() {
    craft()->on('contactForm.beforeSend', function(ContactFormEvent $event) {
        $message = $event->params['message'];
        $ukArray = array('United Kingdom','Wales','Scotland','Ireland');
        $country = '';
        foreach ($message as $key => $field) {
            if($key == 'messageFields') {
                $country = $field['Country'];
            }
        }
        if (in_array($country, $ukArray)) {
            // add an email address to the contact form $toEmails array
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is going to be possible with the current version (1.8.1) of Contact Form.

The only thing passed into the `beforeSend` event is the message, so it doesn't really give you a chance to modify other properties of the email.

Maybe you could pull it off by [dynamically adding these addresses](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#dynamically-adding-email-recipients-requires-craft-25) with some JavaScript that checked selected countries and added to post, but those values are expected to be `|hash`ed.

You could always just fork the plugin and modify it for your specific needs, too.

Comment: Cheers @Brad. I've managed to create some jquery instead to do this. But may look at the plugin at a  later date when I have a bit more time.